# What does "something you are" mean as a verification factor? Can you give some examples?

Tags: security, multi-factor-authentication

Company X uses multi-factor authentication (MFA) to decrease the likelihood of a successful cyber-attacks by requiring one or more additional verification factors: something you know, something you have, or **something you are**.

- Something you know --> e.g. password
- Something you have --> e.g. YubiKey, Duo
- Something you are --> ?

Comment: How did you try to find the answer yourself before asking here? When I type "something you are" into Google, the very first (featured) result says "something you are is an information that is in you — it's a characteristic that only you and no one else has it. That includes, but is not limited to, your fingerprint or thumbprint, palm, handprint, retina, iris, voice and face". Some other results from that Google search may go into more details, if necessary.

Comment: @NotThatGuy I thought googling such as broad sentence ("something you are") would never result in its definition in computer security subject. I'm quite surprised it does.

Comment: It should be understood as "who you are", but it's stated that way to mirror the other factors.

Comment: "I thought googling such as broad sentence ('something you are') would never result in its definition in computer security subject" - I wasn't particularly hopeful about that either, but it was the simplest thing to try. If that didn't work, I would've tried adding "(computer) security" or "(multi-factor) authentication" to the search query, or adding both "something you know" and "something you have" (I expect that many sites will discuss all 3 together), or phrasing it more as an actual question ("what does something you are mean").

Comment: @Barmar *all* authentication boils down to proving who you are; these three methods describe *how* you prove it.

Comment: Except that "something you have" and "something you know" can be transferred, so they don't actually prove who you are. @Shadur Also, it's just kind of strange to refer to a person as "something". Biometrics is more like "something about you physically"

Comment: @Barmar Yes, which is why those are considered slightly less secure than biometrics, but on the other hand biometric authentication requires physical presence, which can be massively inconvenient, so the first two are considered acceptable for most remote authentication. As usual, actually *implemented* security measures have to take into account that they do need to be *used*.

Comment: @Barmar "Something you are" can be transferred. I'm reminded of that scene in Demolition Man...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Something you are refers to biometric identification.
Examples of this could include:

- fingerprint
- voice print
- facial recognition
- vein pattern and blood flow detection
- behavioral biometrics, such as gait or typing timing

This is described in [NIST SP 800-63B section 5.2.3](https://pages.nist.gov/800-63-3/sp800-63b.html#biometric_use) which does not list specific methods, but describes requirements and how to use them.

[Section 10.4](https://pages.nist.gov/800-63-3/sp800-63b.html#biomusability) lists usability considerations of these specific biometrics, including problems with their reliability:

- Fingerprints
- Face
- Iris

Comment: All it takes is good scissors for finger to become something you have.

Comment: ...or something you "don't have", in the case of a running motorbike chain, if you're careless and have a sudden attack of the stupids (_completely hypothetical_)

Comment: "*vein and blood flow detection*" Wouldn't anyone have veins and flowing blood? That doesn't seem like a particularly secure means of verification. The behavioral one also seems horrible for a standard security metric because people can change their gait or typing cadence (among other 'habits') naturally all the time, for many reasons.

Comment: @tylerH Everyone (well, *most* people) have fingerprints, eyes, voices and faces as well. What they're referring to here is that the exact *pattern* of those are Sufficiently Unique to be considered a valid identity marker.

Comment: There's also a slight ableist issue with biometrics because they all assume that you're physically capable of reaching the fingerprint / iris scanner (wheelchair users or people with dwarfism are screwed), voice print (asthmatics; good luck speaking a full sentence for a week or so after a solid asthma attack - speaking from experience), etc.

Comment: @TylerH I heard a story a little while ago about someone that worked in a secure US military facility. He injured his hand over the weekend. After arriving on base he went to work and within 15 minutes he had military police in his office asking him to identify himself. Their security software had picked up on the change to his typing cadence and flagged him as a possible imposter.

Comment: @SteveHiner Sounds like an excellent case study on why that's a stupid metric to use, at least in isolation.

Comment: @TylerH It's stupid for more reasons than that. Biometric data can't be changed like a password, and (unless there have been recent breakthroughs) can't be hashed like a password. Both of these factors increase the severity of the inevitable data breaches.

Comment: It's not vein and blood detection, it's vein pattern and blood flow detection.  I read an article that it is very effective and used in ATMs somewhere.

Comment: Re: abilst / fingers getting damaged:   That sort of problem is exactly what section 10.4 is talking about.  Problems that can come up with biometric identification.  It specifically mentions surgery affecting the ID success.

Comment: NIST does emphasize that some biometric factors are stronger than others, and all of them need to be re-enforced with other methods.